# Saving JSON data using Laravel Transformer

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am working on an API that is pulling data from an xml file then decode it into json, how would the store method look like in the controller?

I have tried storing the json into my DB with code below,  but i cant get to a point were the json gets saved into the DB. A empty record is inserted into my table.

```
public function store(Request $request)

{

$fileContents = file_get_contents('/path/to/my.xml');

$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);

$json = json_encode($simpleXml, true);

Vacancy::create(json_decode($json, true));

}
```

This is my.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exportData>
<requisition>89777</requisition>
<position_title>Data Telecommunication Technician</position_title>
<experience>5 - 7 Years</experience>    
</exportData>
```

This is my Vacancy Model

```
class Vacancy extends Model
{

protected $fillable = ['requisition', 'position_title', 'experience'];
```

I understand that the index method would look like this

```
public function index()

{

$vacancies = Vacancy::all();
return $this->respond([
'data' => $this->vacancyTransformer->transformCollection($vacancies->all())

]);

}
```

This is my VacancyTransformer class

```
class VacancyTransformer extends Transformer 
{

public function transform($vacancy)

{
return [

'requisition' => $vacancy['requisition'],
'position' => $vacancy['position_title'],
'workExperience' => $vacancy['experience'],

];

}

}
```

This is my Transformer class

```
abstract class Transformer {

public function transformCollection(array $items)

{

return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);

}

public abstract function transform($item);

}
```

Comment: The `json_encode` function will return a string with the encoded JSON or false if ti fails. First you should check if the results is not false to make sure the function was successful and more importantly you should decode the string when passing it to the `create` method as that method accepts and array not a string: `Vacancy::create(json_decode($json, true));`.

Comment: @Bogdan your comment is close to what I want to achieve. Problem that I am having now is that a black record is being inserted into the DB table. I will update the question using your input, thanks.

Comment: Please also include the XML file contents.

Comment: @Bogdan i have updated question with xml file.

Comment: I've quickly replicated your scenario and the code for creating a `Vacancy` entry works just fine. With the singe note that the XML structure is invalid as the `requisition` tag is not properly closed (it's missing the `/` in the closing tag), which threw an exception. With that fixed it worked just fine.

Comment: @Bogdan I have fixed the </requisition> sorry about, that was a mistake i did when i was typing the question. You are correct, they is no error being thrown i have tested this using postman but I am still failing to save the data into the DB table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104876/discussion-between-jaahvicky-and-bogdan).